# What notation is required for float.Parse() to detect exponents rather than multiply by 10^n?

Tags: c#, string, parsing, floating-point

That's a bit difficult to write in an easy-to-understand title...

When I run `float.Parse()` on `"12E2"` or `"12e2"` it returns `1200` (`12*10^2`) rather than `144` (`12^2`). This happens with any number, not just this one case.

Edit: Yes, I know 12E2 is not supposed to give 12^2. I’m asking *how* you *are* meant to do it.

What *notation* would be required to have it return a regular *exponent* (eg. `12^2`)?

I've tried using `^`, which throws an error, but I can't seem to tell from the docs what notation is supposed to be used for regular exponents.

Here's my code, not much at all:

```
Debug.Log("text is " + text);
input1 = float.Parse(text.ToString());
Debug.Log("Parsed string to " + input1);
```

It takes the user input `text` and converts it to a float.

Comment: 12 * 100 is 1200, isn't it? `12E2` literally means `12 x 10²`. You want powers `Math.Pow(12, 2)`.

Comment: Nothing... What you want it to a do, is parse a mathematical expression, and its just not designed to do that.

Comment: [Ask Dr. Math's explanation of exponent](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/57140.html#:~:text=The%20e%20stands%20for%20Exponent,multiplied%20by%2010%20sixteen%20times): _"I get 1.524157875019e+16, which 
means that the answer is 1.524157875019 times 10 raised to the 
sixteenth power (that is, multiplied by 10 sixteen times)"_

Comment: I have voted to reopen this question (not because I answered... well maybe a little) ... The close reason has no relevance to the question asked both in the title and the body of the question. "*What notation would be required to have it return a regular exponent* - The question (as far as the standards of stackoverflow go) is fine, even if it has a little misunderstanding in it.

Comment: `12^2` is a math expression, not an integer literal

Comment: [evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have (`12E2`) is standard [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation), and the results you are getting are correct `1200` (`12*10^2`). That is exactly what the `E` means, m × 10<sup>n</sup>.

Furthermore, there are no overloads or options to use `Parse` for regular *power* expressions. `Parse` is just not designed to do arbitrary *mathematical operations* (which is what you are asking)

You can however *parse* it your self to a certain degree and split on `E` or `^` or what ever you like really (assuming this is user input), then *parse* each component to pass into `Math.Pow`.

```
var someWeirdString = "12E2";

var array = someWeirdString.Split('E');

var someFloat = float.Parse(array[0]);
var someInt = int.Parse(array[1]);

var someResult = Math.Pow(someFloat, someInt);

Console.WriteLine(someResult);
```

**Output**

```
144
```